# C data structure

Tags: c

Given an unsorted array `A` of integers, find the pair of elements from `A` for which the sum is 
median(s) over sum of all such pairs. For example if input array

```
A = [7, -37, 2, -3, 9]
```

then the

```
output = (2, -3), (7, -3).
```

I cannot understand what the question asks. I tried but couldn't .

Comment: The OP does not ask for a solution

Comment: The OP's question is implied by "I cannot understan[sic] what the question asks." Frankly, I'm not sure what "sum of all *such* pairs" means myself. Time to ask the professor or TA. (The pairs in the answer appear in the same order in the input array. Is that order significant? No idea.)

Comment: The question asks *"find **the pair** of elements"* so why does the answer have **two pairs**?

Comment: Confusion is regarding the sum. Whether we've to sum all the elements kr pair by pair?

Comment: It's a badly written question, you should ask the person who created the question for clarification.

Comment: I think you're in for a shock if you accept the notion that professors are infallible.

Comment: This looks solvable in O(n*log(n)) time - sort and then walk the ends.  More info needed though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only way I can think that the example makes sense is if the person asking the question is counting the median of an even number of values as the two middle values, rather than the mean of the two middle values, which is how it is normally done.

In the example

```
A = [7, -37, 2, -3, 9]
```

and he wants `sum of all such pairs` I guess for `pair of elements from A`, so the sum of each possible pair, which is

```
(7 + -37) (7 + 2) (7 + -3) (7 + 9) (-37 + 2)....
```

or

```
-40 -35 -30 -28 -4 -1 6 9 11 16
```

The middle two sums are `-4 -1` which are the sums of `(2, -3), (7, -3)`, the answer that was given.

Definitely a very badly worded question, but this kind of makes sense.